# Are two MySQLi queries consecutive when they are consecutive in PHP (even when having multiple hosts)?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to check, if a certain value combination exists in my database.

Therefor I run the following query:

`SELECT status FROM friendships WHERE (userA = (?) AND userB = (?)) OR (userA = (?) AND userB = (?))`with binding `("iiii", $x, $y,  $y, $x`)

If the count of results is 0 I want to `INSERT` something into the table.

Is there a chance that in between those 2 queries the database is changed so that the first condition is not fulfilled but the `INSERT` query is still run?

I'm  especially interested because I may use multiple hosts in future.

And I think `INSERT INTO .. ON DUPLICATE KEY..` won't work as I want to check for a value pair that has no specific order.

Comment: We tend to use LEAST and GREATEST in this context. But yes, to answer your question, outside of a transaction, it's entirely possible that an insert (or delete) operation could occur. You can use INSERT INTO... SELECT syntax to avoid this possibility

Comment: Also, you might consider ALWAYS inserting both pairs - perhaps with a flag to identify the 'real' pair.

Comment: I thought about this but could not think of any practical benefits from it. As it doubles the storage usage could you give me an example where this is beneficial?

Comment: SQL relies on indexes for efficiency. In MySQL, functions cannot use indexes. But if know that both pairs exist, then we no longer need to use LEAST and GREATEST. That's my thinking, anyway.

Comment: If you let PHP bring you variables in order and then `INSERT` them or `SELECT` from the table, there is no need to use MySQL functions that depend on indexing. In this case you do not need `LEAST` or `GREATEST` but just PHP `min()` and `max()`.

Comment: We've conflated two points here; one about race conditions, and one about efficient storage of unordered pairs. You might gain more authoritative answers if you separate those out into two separate questions.

Comment: For scenario in which you think you can't use uniqueness to utilize `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, what @Strawberry suggested is perfectly valid - insert both pairs (or more than 1 pair to be accurate). To clean up the mess, you can schedule an event using MySQL's event scheduler that will perform delete of duplicates. Or, you can sacrifice storage space and simply allow for duplicate entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would impose an order on the two values, so that `userA < userB` is guaranteed. And then if you add a unique index on those two fields, no duplicates can be entered any more.

To enforce the order, you could write a trigger that reverses the order if the wrong order is specified in an `insert` statement.

Here is how you could set it up:

```
create table friendships (
    userA int not null,
    userB int not null,
    primary key (userA, userB)
);

drop trigger if exists trg_friendships_order;
delimiter //

create trigger trg_friendships_order before insert on friendships
for each row
begin
    declare temp int; -- should be same data type as userA & userB
    if new.userB < new.userA then -- swap
        set temp := new.userB;
        set new.userB := new.userA;
        set new.userA := temp;
    end if;
end
//
delimiter /
```

Now when you do this:

```
insert into friendships values (2, 1);
select * from friendships;
```

The output will be:

```
 userA | userB
-------+-------
     1 |     2
```

And so, if you would try to then insert either of the following two:

```
insert into friendships values (2, 1);
insert into friendships values (1, 2);
```

You would get a primary key violation. This condition you can deal with in PHP.